# SQL - How do I add the same Scope_Identity() value in two tables in the same stored procedure, provided I'm adding data into them in the form of TVP?

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I have the following tables -

```
CREATE TABLE Entity 
(
   EntityId INT IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
   EntityName NVARCHAR(20),
   EntityShortName NVARCHAR(5),
   EntityDescription NVARCHAR(100)
)

CREATE TABLE EntityAttributes
(
   EntityId INT FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES Queues(EntityId),
   AttributeType INT,
   AttributeValue NVARCHAR(20)
)
```

And the following TVPs that I'm making use of to add values into these tables -

```
CREATE TYPE TVP_Entity AS TABLE
(
    EntityName NVARCHAR(20),
    EntityShortName NVARCHAR(5),
    EntityDescription NVARCHAR(100)
)

CREATE TYPE TVP_EntityAttributes AS TABLE
(
    AttributeType INT,
    AttributeValue NVARCHAR(20)
)
```

An entity would be defined with Name, ShortName, Description in the first table and other attributes which will be stored in the second table (in EAV form).

I want to write a stored procedure with which I can add multiple entities in a single execution using the TVPs defined above. How can I accomplish this? I'm stuck at the point where I'm unable to use `SCOPE_IDENTITY()` to add values to the second table as I'm inserting multiple entities.

Comment: store in the variable and insert it.

Comment: show your Store procedure

Comment: The `OUTPUT` clause is exactly what you want. It can be used to store values (single or multiple) from a `INSERT / DELETE / UPDATE` statement. Read about it on msdn https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177564.aspx

Comment: If you are adding multiple values to the entity table how do you link the attributes to the correct entity as there is no linkage in your types

Comment: @SteveFord - yes, that is exactly where I'm stuck and this is what I need to solve

Comment: @rohitnair is the EntityName unique, if so could you add this to the attributes type?

Comment: @SteveFord Yes I can make it unique and add it to the attributes type, but how will that help?

Comment: @rohitnair see my answer

Comment: Thank you @SteveFord, this works perfectly. But I would also want to know how I can accomplish this if EntityName wasn't unique?

Comment: @rohitnair in that case you would have to add some column to your attributes & entity types to allow you to link them.

Comment: @rohitnair did my answer answer your question, if so accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this by adding the EntityName to the TVP_EntityAttributes type. Full example:

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/300db/1)

**MS SQL Server 2008 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE Entity 
(
   EntityId INT IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
   EntityName NVARCHAR(20) UNIQUE,
   EntityShortName NVARCHAR(5),
   EntityDescription NVARCHAR(100)
)

CREATE TABLE EntityAttributes
(
   EntityId INT FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES Entity(EntityId),
   AttributeType INT,
   AttributeValue NVARCHAR(20)
)

CREATE TYPE TVP_Entity AS TABLE
(
   EntityName NVARCHAR(20),
   EntityShortName NVARCHAR(5),
   EntityDescription NVARCHAR(100)
)

CREATE TYPE TVP_EntityAttributes AS TABLE
(
   EntityName NVARCHAR(20),
   AttributeType INT,
   AttributeValue NVARCHAR(20)
)
GO
```

Now add your stored procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE AddEntity
(
  @entities TVP_Entity READONLY, 
  @attributes TVP_EntityAttributes READONLY
)
AS

    INSERT INTO Entity(EntityName, EntityShortName, EntityDescription)
    SELECT [EntityName], [EntityShortName], [EntityDescription]
    FROM @entities


    INSERT INTO EntityAttributes([EntityId],[AttributeType],[AttributeValue])
    SELECT E.EntityId, A.[AttributeType], A.[AttributeValue]
    FROM Entity E
    INNER JOIN @attributes A
        ON E.EntityName = A.EntityName
```

**Query 1**:

```
DECLARE @entities TVP_Entity
DECLARE @attributes TVP_EntityAttributes

INSERT INTO @entities(EntityName, EntityShortName, EntityDescription)
SELECT 'Entity1', 'E1', 'Entity One'
UNION
SELECT 'Entity2', 'E2', 'Entity Two'
UNION
SELECT 'Entity3', 'E3', 'Entity Three'


INSERT INTO @Attributes( EntityName,AttributeType,AttributeValue)
SELECT 'Entity1', 1, 2
UNION
SELECT 'Entity1', 2, 3
UNION
SELECT 'Entity2', 3, 2
UNION
SELECT 'Entity2', 4, 3
UNION
SELECT 'Entity3', 5, 4
UNION
SELECT 'Entity3', 6, 4
UNION
SELECT 'Entity3', 7, 21
UNION
SELECT 'Entity3', 8, 32


EXEC AddEntity @entities ,  @attributes 

SELECT *
FROM Entity E
INNER JOIN EntityAttributes EA
    ON E.EntityId = EA.EntityId
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/300db/1/0)**:

```
| EntityId | EntityName | EntityShortName | EntityDescription | EntityId | AttributeType | AttributeValue |
|----------|------------|-----------------|-------------------|----------|---------------|----------------|
|        1 |    Entity1 |              E1 |        Entity One |        1 |             1 |              2 |
|        1 |    Entity1 |              E1 |        Entity One |        1 |             2 |              3 |
|        2 |    Entity2 |              E2 |        Entity Two |        2 |             3 |              2 |
|        2 |    Entity2 |              E2 |        Entity Two |        2 |             4 |              3 |
|        3 |    Entity3 |              E3 |      Entity Three |        3 |             5 |              4 |
|        3 |    Entity3 |              E3 |      Entity Three |        3 |             6 |              4 |
|        3 |    Entity3 |              E3 |      Entity Three |        3 |             7 |             21 |
|        3 |    Entity3 |              E3 |      Entity Three |        3 |             8 |             32 |
```